# request a json parameter to java to convert a json array to java array

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, jsp

Basicaly I need to to pass an java String array to javascipt array,  after that pass this array via json to jsp page, in jsp parse this array as java array.

I try the following:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
JSONObject tmp;

    for(int i = 0; i < invoiceid.length; i++) {
         tmp = new JSONObject();
         tmp.put("invoiceid", invoiceid[i]);
         arr.add(tmp);
    }
```

following javascript in the same page:

```
var invoiceid = JSON.stringify(<%=arr%>);`
$.ajax({
                     type: 'GET',
                     url: 'crudsettlement.jsp',
                     data: {
                         Winvoiceid: invoiceid
                     },
                     async: false,
                     dataType: 'json',
                     success: function(json) {
                         $("#msg").val(json.msg);
                     }
                 });
```

In page crudsettlement.jsp I try the following:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("mydata"));
```

but i take the folloing error 
   incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Map

any idea on how to to convert the json array to java array? I use json-simple.

Comment: First try out this `String ex = request.getParameter("mydata")` print out `ex` and post a sample here.

Comment: `[{"invoiceid":"0147708"}]`

Comment: Okay first get `mydata` as String and then parse that string as jsonarray and then convert it as java array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know your JSON well , here is the rough logic

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(request.getParameter("mydata"));
List<String> jsonList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    jsonList.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("invoice"));
}
String[] invoices = jsonList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Update , tried the below it seems to work :

```
String json = " [{\"invoiceid\":\"0147708\"}]";

JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(json);
//JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("invoiceid");

List<String> jsonList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    jsonList.add(((JSONObject) array.get(i)).toString());
}
String[] invoices = jsonList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Ramachandran G A when I write the the following: 
`JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(request.getParameter("mydata"));`
I take the following error:
`incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Map`

Comment: Can you share how your JSON looks like. Most likely the string is a singular value with a nested array and i am directly casting it to an array

Comment: I have download the json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Comment: Ramachandran G A the command `JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(request.getParameter("mydata"));` is not accepted. In `new JSONArray()` need a Map